# Configurate Apache 2.4 reverse proxy with redirection

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, mod-rewrite

**Server1** runs **apache proxy** and **webserver tomcat** domain: `example.com/app1`. **Server2** runs just **webserver tomcat** `example.com/app2`. I'd like to redirect `example.com/` to `example.com/app1` and app2 server not redirect just stay on `example.com/app2`. Also need redirection all pages from http to https. Some things doesnt comunicate properly between app1 and app2 servers - I see error 500.

```
**hhtpd.conf on Server1:**
    Listen 80
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
    RedirectMatch "^/$" "https://example.com/app1/"
```

```
**ssl.conf on Server1:**
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName example.com
    SSLEngine on
    Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"
    <Proxy *>
            Require all granted
    </Proxy>
    SSLProxyEngine          On
    ProxyRequests           Off
    ProxyPreserveHost       On
    ProxyPass               /app1       http://localhost:8080/app1
    ProxyPassReverse        /app1       http://localhost:8080/app1
    ProxyPass               /app2       http://192.168.11.8:8090/app2
    ProxyPassReverse        /app2       http://192.168.11.8:8090/app2
```

Can I use RewriteEngine with reverse proxy?